# Pressing tab in HTML files in vim goes to the next empty tag pair rather than expanding a completion

Tags: vim, snipmate

I'm not sure where the functionality of tabbing to the next empty tag pair in HTML files comes from. I would like to disable it completely.

The problem only comes with using SuperTab and SnipMate together, if I remove SuperTab tab goes back to expanding normally, if I remove SnipMate, tab goes back to showing completions.

In the past I've had both working fine and would like to do so again.

I'm using:

```
http://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim
http://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets
http://github.com/ervandew/supertab
```

With vim-update-bundles. Default configuration for both. Other options I have enabled are syntax on. autoindent. smartindent. expandtab. nocompatible. filetype indent plugin on.

Comment: I used to have the same problem, except it is because of SuperTab and Sparkup.

Comment: Same problem += markdown files.

Answer (score 2):

SnipMate and SuperTab both use <kbd>⇥</kbd>, that makes their combination very annoying and unpredictable.

After years of TextMate, <kbd>⇥</kbd> expansion was a habit I couldn't/didn't want to drop so I ditched SuperTab quickly and learned to love Vim's native Omni Completion:

```
inoremap <leader>, <C-x><C-o>
inoremap <leader>: <C-x><C-f>
inoremap <leader>= <C-x><C-l>
```

For a more streamlined experience, [autocomplpop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) is surprisingly fast and smart.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that fit my needs is [neocomplcache](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620).

It's a nice mix between autocomplpop, supertab and snipmate. Well, the snippet part is just a little buggy, but quite usable.

However I don't use <kbd>⇥</kbd> to expand, the popup omnicompletion comes up after the 3rd written character. You move with <kbd>⇥</kbd> thru the list, and expand the snippets (a la textmate), with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, but you can map that to you choice.

These are my `.vimrc` settings.

```
        """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""
        " => neocomplcache plugin
        """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""
        " TODO: Still need to tweak behavior with <TAB> to expand
        "       snippets, change throughout the autocompletion list

        " Use neocomplcache.
        let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1
        " Use smartcase.
        let g:neocomplcache_enable_smart_case = 1
        " Use camel case completion.
        let g:neocomplcache_enable_camel_case_completion = 1
        " Use underbar completion.
        let g:neocomplcache_enable_underbar_completion = 1
        " Set minimum syntax keyword length.
        let g:neocomplcache_min_syntax_length = 3
        let g:neocomplcache_lock_buffer_name_pattern = '\*ku\*'
        let g:neocomplcache_snippets_dir = '~/.vim/snippet/'
        " Define dictionary.
        let g:neocomplcache_dictionary_filetype_lists = {
                    \ 'default' : '',
                    \ 'vimshell' : $HOME.'/.vimshell_hist',
                    \ 'scheme' : $HOME.'/.gosh_completions'
                    \ }

        " Define keyword.
        if !exists('g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns')
            let g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns = {}
        endif
        let g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns['default'] = '\h\w*'

        " Plugin key-mappings.
        imap <C-k>     <Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand)
        smap <C-k>     <Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand)
        inoremap <expr><C-g>     neocomplcache#undo_completion()
        inoremap <expr><C-l>     neocomplcache#complete_common_string()

        " SuperTab like snippets behavior.
        imap <expr><TAB> neocomplcache#sources#snippets_complete#expandable() ? "\<Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand)" : pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"

        " Recommended key-mappings.
        " <CR>: close popup and save indent.
        " inoremap <expr><CR>  neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\<CR>"
        " <TAB>: completion.
        inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
        " <C-h>, <BS>: close popup and delete backword char.
        inoremap <expr><C-h> neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
        inoremap <expr><BS> neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
        inoremap <expr><C-y>  neocomplcache#close_popup()
        inoremap <expr><C-e>  neocomplcache#cancel_popup()

        " AutoComplPop like behavior.
        "let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1

        " Shell like behavior(not recommended).
        "set completeopt+=longest
        "let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1
        "let g:neocomplcache_disable_auto_complete = 1
        "inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<TAB>"
        "inoremap <expr><CR>  neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\<CR>"

        " Enable omni completion.
        autocmd FileType css setlocal omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
        autocmd FileType html,markdown setlocal omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
        autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
        autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
        autocmd FileType xml setlocal omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags

        " Enable heavy omni completion.
        if !exists('g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns')
            let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns = {}
        endif
        let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.ruby = '[^. *\t]\.\w*\|\h\w*::'
        "autocmd FileType ruby setlocal omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
        let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.php = '[^. \t]->\h\w*\|\h\w*::'

        au BufNewFile,BufRead *.snip set syntax=snippet ft=snippet foldmethod=indent
```